# Add class to the last child of element after page load

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

My code:

```
  <script>

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/chatbot/fetch/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)

        if (data.choices !== '') {

          const htmlAnswer = data.answer.map(answer => {
            return `
              <button
                class="max-w-sm py-3 px-4 focus:outline-none text-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-100 text-center transition ease-in-out duration-300">
                ‍ &nbsp; ${answer}
              </button>
            `
          }).join('')

          document.getElementById('server-message').innerHTML = `
            <div class="flex flex-col shadow rounded-lg my-3 max-w-sm border hover:border-indigo-300 hover:shadow-lg transition ease-in-out duration-300">
              <div class="mb-0 py-3 px-4 max-w-sm bg-gray-200 rounded-lg rounded-b-none select-none">
              ${data.question}
              </div>
              ${htmlAnswer}
            </div>
            `
          }
          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
          document.getElementById("server-message").lastElementChild.classList.add('rounded-b-lg');
          })

      })

  </script>
```

I want to add class to the last child of the parent. I am rendering both parent and child elements from `JSON`. How can I get it work?

Probably it should start looking for a child element after these are rendered into the `HTML`. I don't know how to do it.

I need it in vanilla js.

Comment: P.S. I looked other questions but they didn't work for me.

Comment: If the `DOMContentLoaded` event happens before your script creates that event listener, i'm 99.9999% sure its logic will not happen

Comment: @Taplar How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help. I check the last item in map function and add the class to it

```
const answerLength = data.answer.length
  const htmlAnswer = data.answer.map((answer,index)=> {
// if this is the last element then add the class 
if(index+1 ==answerLength){

            return `
              <button
                class="max-w-sm py-3 px-4 focus:outline-none text-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-100 text-center transition ease-in-out duration-300 rounded-b-lg">
                ‍ &nbsp; ${answer}
              </button>
            `
}
else{
            return `
              <button
                class="max-w-sm py-3 px-4 focus:outline-none text-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-100 text-center transition ease-in-out duration-300">
                ‍ &nbsp; ${answer}
              </button>
            `
}
          }).join('')
```